# Set Jenkins "Global Tool Configuration" properties using script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-api

I am trying to deploy the jenkins pod through docker and configure the Jenkins Jobs through the scripts. Using some of below restAPIs

```
a) https://<hostname>/scriptText
b) https://<hostname>/job//build
c) https://<hostname>/job/api/json
.
.
and more
```

However when I start building jobs, its getting failed due to the error **ERROR: Unable to install JDK unless a valid username/password is provided.**

It needs to change the configurations from **Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> JDK -> JDK Installations**

But there is no any restAPI available to perform this task.

Is there any way to change the jenkins global configuration programatically?

Comment: I am not sure i understood the problem: if your goal is to install JDK on runtime if needed automatic you can go to the URL: <YOUR JENKINS IP>:8080/configureTools/  Press JDK, Give name-> Install automatic -> Install from Java sun (press i agree button)

Comment: @OronGolan proper JDK version already installed on master/slave nodes. But I want to change the default configuration of jenkins "Global Tool Configuration" about JDK which asks to install JDK on each build start using script (Not using UI).

Answer (score 1):

One solution I found is that, set username and password to download the JDK from oracle site in **Global Tool Configuration**.

To do it, execute below groovy script using scriptText rest api

> set_username_password.groovy

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*

def inst = Jenkins.getInstance()
def desc = inst.getDescriptor("hudson.tools.JDKInstaller")
#create user account here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
println desc.doPostCredential('<username>','<password>')
```

Execute the rest api as

```
curl --user <jk_username>:<jk_password> --data-urlencode "script=$(cat set_username_password.groovy)" -X POST "https://<hostname>/scriptText"
```

> References:

https://github.com/glenjamin/jenkins-groovy-examples/blob/master/README.md

http://javadoc.jenkins.io/archive/jenkins-2.73/hudson/tools/JDKInstaller.DescriptorImpl.html